# How do I get the public IP of an EC2 instance with v3 of the AWS SDK for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work:

```js
const { EC2Client, DescribeAddressesCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-ec2');

const client = new EC2Client({
    region: 'us-west-1',
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: '',
        secretAccessKey: ''
    }
});

client.send(new DescribeAddressesCommand({
    Filters: [
        {
            Name: 'instance-id',
            Values: [
                ''
            ]
        }
    ]
})).then(console.log);
```

It outputs an empty array:

```
{
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: '',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  Addresses: []
}
```

I have tried this: [How to get EC2 public ip using aws-sdk Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739524/how-to-get-ec2-public-ip-using-aws-sdk-javascript)

Comment: Do you want to know _all_ of the Elastic IPs, or just for one instance? If for one instance, why didn't you put the Instance ID in the `Values` section?

Comment: I did; it is redacted for SO.

Comment: It is difficult to know what you have 'redacted' and what the Code and Response actually contains. Did you redact anything in the response? If so, please just insert a fake value. Are you saying that the result contained `Addresses: []` (with nothing redacted)? What happens if you do it without specifying an Instance ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured a solution and that is to use the internal endpoint to get the IP and then store in a database for future use.

Thank you for all the help.